# How do I call a function in scheme?

Tags: function, scheme, lisp

I'm trying to call a recursive call in scheme. All I am getting is errors that I don't understand.

```
(define removeFirst (lambda (N L)
(cond 

( (null? L)  '()  )  

( (= (car L) N)   (removeFirst(N cdr L))                     )

( #t          (cons (car L) (removeFirst(N cdr L)) )          )         )

)
))
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Perhaps after you fix the syntax error with regards to the call to `removeFirst`  and `cdr` you can update your question with more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algol/C call style:

```
funName(arg1, arg2)
```

Lisp call style:

```
(fun-name arg1 arg2)
```

Doing

```
(removeFirst (N cdr L))
```

Is the same as:

```
removeFirst(N(cdr, L));
```

Perfectly ok as long as `N` is a function, but you also compare `N` with a number so there is at least one error in your code on your use of `N`. Extra parentheses in C are often ignored, never in Lisp. They are essential to the meaning of the code. You probably meant to write the completely different code:

```
(removeFirst N (cdr L))
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I did mean to write (removeFirst N (cdr L)). Unfortunately that does not solve the abundant error messages, so looks like its only the first problem with the code it solved. But that does answer the question I asked so thanks.